# Problemas al instalar express desde VSCODE

Tags: javascript, express

Cada vez que intento instalarlo, sea en el directorio que sea, me salta el siguiente error. Ya he probado, varias veces, con pnpm i express.

````
npm i express
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bd","tarball":"https:'```
````

Comment: ¿Usas `npm` o `pnpm`? Seguramente tengas algún fichero `package.json` corrupto o similar. Intenta hacer la instalación sobre un proyecto nuevo vacío.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta actualizar **npm**:

```
npm update -g npm
```

O finalmente, prueba con:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Alguno de los dos debería arreglar tu problema...